# How can I get the name of a directory with an unknown specific pattern, then cd to it (in bash, on macOS)

Tags: bash, macos, directory, wildcard

I have a lots of subjects, each with a 2 or 3 sub-directories that have the pattern of "subjectname_XXX_aslpp". The XXX is different between sub-dirs and subjects.

I have a large loop that goes through each subject, but I need to operate on a specific file in each of the "subjectname_XXX_aslpp" directories, so I need to know its pathname.

e.g. If for subject 1, I have 3 subdirs (changes between subs!), XXX=123, 758, 294, then my loop needs to jump into that subject, then operate on a file inside each of those folders.

```
mycommand subject1/subjectname_123_aslpp/diffav_calib.nii.gz

mycommand subject1/subjectname_758_aslpp/diffav_calib.nii.gz

mycommand subject1/subjectname_294_aslpp/diffav_calib.nii.gz
```

For example

```
MOUNT="/mypath/to/data/"
for subject in $subjectlist
do
   for numDir in $howmanysubdirs
   do
        myfunction ${MOUNT}/${subject}/${subject}_XXX_aslpp/diffav_calib.nii.gz
        ...
   done
done
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: So if you `cd` to where the data is and do `find subject1 subject3 -type d -name "*aslpp"` does that get you close?

Comment: Yes I've been playing around with `test=$(find ${MOUNT}/${subject} -type d -name "*_aslpp")`, but then it saves all pathnames, say 3 of the subdirs into the variable test. Then not super sure how to index them out in bash

Comment: you need to either ```for file in $(find ${MOUNT}/${subject}/ -name 'diffav_calib.nii.gz' );do myfunction $file;done``` or ```find ${MOUNT}/${subject}/ -name 'diffav_calib.nii.gz' -exec myfunction {} \;``` - both should work

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny This worked a charm
`for file in $(find ${MOUNT}/${subject}/ -name 'diffav_calib.nii.gz' );do myfunction $file;done`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working, thank you!
@MaximSagaydachny

```
for file in $(find ${MOUNT}/${subject}/ -name 'diffav_calib.nii.gz' );
            do 
                echo $file
                tmpPath=$(dirname $file)

                echo $tmpPath

                flirt -in $file\
                    -ref ${ANATMOUNT}/${anatsub}.nii\
                    -out $tmpPath/diffav_calib_flirt\
                    -omat $tmpPath/diffav_calib_flirt.mat\
                    -bins 256\
                    -cost corratio\
                    -searchrx -90 90\
                    -searchry -90 90\
                    -searchrz -90 90\
                    -dof 12\
                    -interp trilinear
            done
```